# How to build a circuit which allows a piezo transducer to act as both a transmitter and receiver

Tags: transmitter, receiver, ultrasound, transducer

I am a student and am currently working on a project where I require a piezo transducer to act as both a transmitter and receiver. I am finding it difficult to build a circuit where a pulse can be transmitted to the piezo and then the transmit side is isolated so that the received pulse at the transducer can be acquired and processed. At the moment, my circuit consists of a burst generator which outputs 5V square-waves at 1.1MHz with a programmable number of cycles.

After doing some research, I came across the MD0100 which is a High-Voltage Protection T/R switch. The data sheet can be accessed by the link below:

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MD0100-Single-and-Dual-Channel%20High-Voltage-Protection-TR-Switch-Data-Sheet-20005738A.pdf

I thought that this switch would work for what I am trying to achieve. At the moment, my circuit looks something like the schematic below.
[image: Schematic of current T/R circuit]

The problem that I am having with this switch is that once I connect my burst generator to the circuit above, it goes from originally looking like this:
[image: Transmitter output]

To becoming cut down and looking like this:
[image: Transmitter output when connected to MD0100]

My burst generator is limited to an amplitude of 5V. However, using a bench signal generator, I varied the amplitude of the square-waves to see if the problem was the same. Once the amplitude of the square-wave was set to 6V or above, it seemed to look fine as can be seen below:
[image: 6V square-wave burst]

With the square-waves above being applied to the piezo, the received signal was acquired at the receiver, and looked good:
[image: Received piezo signal when 6V square-wave burst applied]

Since my burst generator is limited to 5V amplitude, either I need to find a way of fixing the issue with the MD0100 as to why it is ruining my bursts at 5V amplitudes, or I need to build an alternative T/R circuit. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do or can recommend an alternative simple circuit that I could build instead? Thank you.

Comment: It would seem that your transmitter is too feeble to overcome the 15 ohm resistance presented by the switch. A lower-impedance transmit driver might help. It would also help if your transmitter was capable of more voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a circuitry which can help, to be adapted to your sensor ...
It was used for 40 kHz sensor.

Voltage of driver may be changed and tuned (or not) transformer ratio too. [image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple T/R switch where you need a low-noise receiver chain:

[image: schematic]

Some rules:

- D1 & D2 must handle your peak transmit current and be fast diodes. Depending on current flowing thru the diodes, you may get 1Vp signal. This will reduce the transducer drive signal by this voltage drop which usually isn't a problem if driving over 10V.
- R1, D3, D4 may not be necessary. Only use if the voltage across D1 & D2 is too high for your receiver input. D3 & D4 can be 1N4148, or equivalent, as the current is small. This combination will see about 0.5 to 0.6 Vp across D3 & D4.
- During the receive period, the power amplifier must short the primary of the transformer so the output impedance will be low. If using an H-bridge, turn the bottom transistors on during the receive period. This also ensures a proper startup of the charge pump circuit in most half bridge drivers. This will also reduce noise injection from other circuitry since the transformer windings have capacitive coupling (usually a few pF).
- The bias resistor for your preamplifier (not shown, but will be across D4) should be as high as possible if this is a wide band design, low-noise design. A high value bias resistor (depending on the transducer impedance, around 100k to 10Mohms) will improve noise at the low frequency end. This suggests using some sort of FET input amplifier which will have excellent current noise (around \$15 fA/\sqrt{Hz}\$) and fairly good input voltage noise (around  \$4 nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$). Of course, when you get in the megohm region, the diode off resistance will be around 5Mohms.